# what determines the size of socket data event in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sockets

I want to know what determines the size of data when a tcp socket emitted an 'data' event as following, thx!

```
    var client = new Socket(options);
    client.on('data', chunk => {}); // what determines the size of chunk?
```

Answer (score 3):

When a `IP packet` with a`TCP segment` arrives, the data contained will be pushed into the internal buffer of `net.Socket` (which is a [duplex stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_duplex) ) with [`stream.push(chunk)`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_push_chunk_encoding).

**Provided that `net.Socket` is in flowing mode**, the data added with `stream.push(chunk)` will be delivered with a `'data'` event. As a result, the size of the `chunk` **corresponds to the data of the `TCP segment` which arrived.**

However, if the stream is paused and then resumed, the chunk released afterwards will not correspond to the data contained to a single `TCP segment`.

The stream internal buffer can hold data up to `highWaterMark` threshold.

See details on `buffering` and `highWaterMark` here:
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_buffering

Answer (score 0):

The size of chunk is not deterministic.

For a specific amount of data to be received, `data` could be emitted once with a big chunk, or be emitted multiple times with small chunks.